# How to convert the sql to jpa criteria query for hibernate or eclipse link

Tags: hibernate, eclipselink, criteria

I have a table with

```
Id      value 
1000    null
1000    En
1000    Fr
1000    Es
1001    En
1001    Fr
1001    Es
```

Output of the select query should be as follows. (Since 1000 has a null value only, select the row with null value)

```
Id      value
1000    null
1001    En
1001    Fr
1001    Es
```

I got a select query as given below from the stack over flow([How to to give preference to null value during select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133323/how-to-to-give-preference-to-null-value-during-select)), how to convert the same query to jpa criteria for hibernate or eclipse link

```sql
select query 
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.value
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                                      AND t2.value IS NULL)
              OR t1.value IS NULL;
```

Assume my entity class is 
class Test{

```
private String id;

private String value;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

List getTests() {

```
            final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            final CriteriaQuery<Test> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Test.class);

            Root<Test> TestRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Test.class);

            Subquery<Test> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Test.class);

            Root<Test> subQueryTestRoot = subquery.from(Test.class);

            subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(subQueryTestRoot.get(Test_.value).isNull()), criteriaBuilder
                    .equal(TestRoot.get(Test_.id), subQueryTestRoot.get(Test_.id)));


            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.or(TestRoot.get(Test_.value).isNull(), criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery))));

            TypedQuery<Test> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);


            return typedQuery.getResultList();
        }
```